# JSON and Generics in Java - Type safety warning

Tags: java, json, eclipse, generics

I have some data stored in Java elements and I need to return it in a given format - JSONObject. While my implementation works fine, I'm still getting a warning message from eclipse (Version: Juno Service Release 2):

"*Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap should be parameterized*"

This is my code:

```
public interface Element {...}

public abstract class AbstractElement implements Element {...}

public final class Way extends AbstractElement {...}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class WayToJsonConverter{
    ...
    public JSONObject wayToJson(){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("id",way.getId());
        ...
        return obj;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problematic line is : `obj.put("id",way.getId());`

Is there a way to solve this issue other then adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: what is the return type of `getId()`?

Comment: The return type is : String

Comment: In that case, there is no problem with `obj.put("id",way.getId());`. It has to be some other line which gives that warning!

Comment: Would be helpful if you added your `import` section to the code snippet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What is your JSONObject, does it inherit from HashMap? If does, the warn probably means that your should declare the JSONObject instance as follows:

```
JSONObject<String,Object> obj=new JSONObject<String,Object>();
```

Updated: Look at the definition of the JSONObject:

```
public class JSONObject extends HashMap
```

it extends HashMap but doesn't support parameter type, if its definition is

```
public class JSONObject<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>
```

then we could write

```
JSONObject<String,Object> obj=new JSONObject<String,Object>();
```

and the put method will no longer generate the warning

Comment: When I'm trying to do that I'm getting the message: "The type JSONObject is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Object>"

Comment: I found it extends HashMap, but does not have type parameter in class definition, so we can do nothing rather than adding the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") here...

Comment: Can you add the last comment's content to your answer? You were the first to explain why this cannot be solved and I want to accept your answer.

Comment: Look at the definition of the JSONObject:"public class JSONObject extends HashMap", it extends HashMap but doesn't support parameter type, if it's definition is "public class JSONObject<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>", then we could write "JSONObject<String,Object> obj=new JSONObject<String,Object>();", and the put method will no longer generate the warning

Comment: I am using the same `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;` The latests versions seems to be 1.1.1. Is there a newer version that can be parameterized? This is the one I have: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

Comment: Type 'org.json.simple.JSONObject' does not have type parameter

Answer (score 2):

If you can't switch to another library or modify the code of this library to make it generic, the only other option would be to write a wrapper around this library which uses it, and properly supports generics.

So you would have your own `JSONObject` class which would contain an `org.json.simple.JSONObject`, would extend `HashMap<String, Object>` and implement `Map<String, Object>`, and would contain forwarding methods for all the methods of `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

You would still have to put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in this class, but it would be limited to this class, and all the rest of your code could be free of generic warnings or the suppression of them.

Comment: If I still need to use the suppressWarning I didn't solved the problem but moved it. As for now, all of the JSON handling are done in one class so it won't help me much. Moreover, I need to return a JSONObject to some methods of the interface I'm implementing so Warping it won't help me anyway. It seems that this is a limitation of the given JSON package and I can't do much to make it look better.

Answer (score 2):

public class JSONObject extends HashMap implements Map, JSONAware, JSONStreamAware

But does not have type parameter in class definition, The only option you have is to add the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 0):

FYI `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` will not cause this warning. When using codehaus' JSONObject, you also have the ability to catch parsing errors via `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException`. See https://github.com/codehaus/jettison for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map object and then do an explicit cast to JSONObject

```
Map<String, String> obj =  new HashMap<String, String>();
obj.put("id",way.getId());
JSONObject jsonObj =  (JSONObject) obj;
```

But note that this will restrict you only include "Strings" in your JSON. and you will see compile errors if you put another data structure. Say an array.

Comment: in the above case there is no need to add "suppress warning" annotation

Comment: `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to initialize the `JSONObject` with a (parameterized) `Map<String, Object>`. That way, a value can be of any valid JSON type, and you avoid the `unchecked` warning. E.g.:

```
public class WayToJsonConverter{
    ...
    public JSONObject wayToJson(){
        Map<String, Object> forJsonObj = new HashMap<>();
        forJsonObj.put("id",way.getId());  // No warning, hurray!
        forJsonObj.put("integer", 14);
        forJsonObj.put("floating", 1.4);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(forJsonObj);
        ...
        return obj;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `JSONObject` has no parameterized constructors.

Comment: @HarshPandey- I don't use a parameterized constructor of `JSONObject` in my answer.

Comment: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(forJsonObj);`
are you not using a parameterized constructor here?

Comment: Oh, you mean that the constructor receives a `Map` argument in the constructor? I misunderstood your comment. Anyway, I was using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map)) as a reference.

Comment: Your reference points to `org.json.JSONObject`, while OP is using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

Comment: `org.json.simple.JSONObject` also has a parameterized constructor which accepts a `Map`: http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map)

Comment: I understand the confusion now.
[This](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html) implementation of `JSONObject` does indeed have a parameterized constructor. The [implementation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) that I am using [does not have a parameterized constructor](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/a8b94b79b697df64b23428c27d65d6a187e9ebf9/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java).

Comment: Actually, the implementation you referenced *does* have a [parameterized constructor](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/a8b94b79b697df64b23428c27d65d6a187e9ebf9/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java#L34).

Comment: Haha, sorry, I must've found the wrong one. The one that I am currently using in production does not have a parameterized constructor. But I am switching to one that does have it.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the **put** line to other

```
 JsonPath.parse(jsonObj).set(fieldPath, Value);
```