# How to solve the following warning?

Tags: java, jsp

Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap should be parameterized.

Answer (score 3):

Probably somewhere in your code you have

```
Map map = new HashMap();
```

you should parameterize this with the **types** of your *keys* and *values* in your hashmap. For example, if you use `String` keys en `SomeObject` objects, you should use:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> map = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();
```

Comment: Actually warning is in below code :
<%
String msg="Hello";
out.println(msg);
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("JamInformation",msg);
%>

Comment: Then take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415436/json-and-generics-in-java-type-safety-warning

Answer (score 0):

Use Generics for defining your collection like below.

`List<String> list=new ArrayList<String> ();`

For your case it is a map so you can use

`Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();`

It will be a good practise if u will define `immutable` object as `keys` like `String class`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to create a hashmap is

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

You can replace String and Integer with whatever class you want.  The first one is the class the all keys must be and the second one what all values must be.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should not use this. With generics collection types expect you to be more specific about the type of objects you will be putting in the map as key and value objects. Generics help enforce what is called as compile time type checks.

But if you still insist on using it as this then use the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation on your method in which you are getting this warning or just above the code statement which is giving this warning. But then the burden falls on you to cast the type of the object after you get them form the map and use in your code. Problems in code because of wrong type cases across inheritance hierarchies would only be visible at runtime when the jvm throws a class caste exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic `HashMap<T1, T2>` and try to add a key-value pair to it that is not of type T1 and T2. I.e. you have:

```
HashMap<T1, T2> map = ...;
Object o1
Object o2;
// ...
map.put(o1, o2);     // generates warning
```

You want:

```
HashMap<T1, T2> map = ...;
T1 o1;
T2 o2;
// ...
map.put(o1, o2);     // no warning - notice the types!
```

This is because generics in Java are only emulated. The type `HashMap<T1, T2>` only exists at compile time and is really a fancier way of declaring your good old non-generic `HashMap`. As such, it still has the original `put(Object, Object)` method. In other languages, such as C#, that method would not exist, and you would have a `put(T1, T2)` method instead.

For more info, see [What is wrong with Java's generics?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22642/what-is-wrong-with-javas-generics).