# Writing array of objects to a file with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

```
public boolean wirteJson(Passenger passenger[]){
    try {
        file = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String json =gson.toJson(passenger[i]);
            file.write(json);
        }
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to write the `passenger` array to a file with Gson. I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: Okay, so what's your question?

Comment: There's a pretty good solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728446/write-a-json-file-in-java

Comment: sorry i think my question was unclear my problem is writing array of object   to file and then read it

Comment: Did you read the [Gson user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)? First, there is a method that writes the JSON directly to a `Writer` - no need to convert to a string first and then write. Second, if you want to read the JSON into a particular data type, you need to use the methods that have a `Type` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to serialize the given input array by each element:

- Gson can do it all itself;
- your method assumes the input array is exactly 10 elements long (thus, throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the input array has less elements, or writing only first 10 elements);
- your method does not write well-formed JSON: `{},{},{}` is invalid, whilst `[{},{},{}]` is;
- your method, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439637/writing-array-of-objects-to-a-file-with-gson#comment73936696_43439637) by [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic), does not need intermediate string representations.

All you need are just two methods [Gson.toJson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.Appendable-) and [Gson.fromJson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Class-).
So, here is a simple example:

```java
final class Passenger {

    final String name;

    Passenger(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final File file = createTempFile("q43439637_", "_q43439637");
    file.deleteOnExit();
    try ( final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file) ) {
        final Passenger[] before = { new Passenger("Alice"), new Passenger("Bob") };
        gson.toJson(before, fileWriter);
    }
    try ( final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file) ) {
        final Passenger[] after = gson.fromJson(fileReader, Passenger[].class);
        for ( final Passenger p : after ) {
            System.out.println(p.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Alice
>   Bob

P.S. Your out-of-`catch` `return` seems to have to return `true` rather than `false`. Also, `flush()` is unnecessary before `close()`.

Comment: Actually, I did a mistake. It is. Thanks.