# How write a JSON object in a file

Tags: java, vue.js

I have a JSON object which is a list of elements, each elements is an array that contains: Name, Id and Quantity. Having already the JSON object saved on the servlet, I just have to take it and write it through writer.write to a .txt file.

```
ArrayList<EntryList> al = new ArrayList<>();

      public void inserisci(@RequestBody EntryList item) 
     {
         item.setId(al.size());
         item.setQuantity(item.getQuantity());

         al.add(item);

         try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/file.txt");

                for (EntryList el : al)
                {
                   writer.write(el.toString());
                }

              }
              writer.close();

              catch (Exception e) {

                 }
```

But this way it just writes the name of the element. How can I solve it?

Comment: What is `al`? You can't show variables and not show is type

Comment: What's an EntryList? Is this the SAP OData client library?

Comment: please show your json Object code.  and  al variable code.

Comment: Reformat the code. It's also syntactically wrong.

Comment: create a class like class with params: myobject(String Name, int id, int quantity):
define a  constructor, and toString method, and add it in your for loop for(entry: jsonarray){m= New myobject(al[entry]['data'],al[entry]['id'],al[entry]['quantity']); arrraylist.add(m)}
print arraylist<m>;

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728446/write-a-json-file-in-java

Comment: I'm very sorry. EntryList is a class, my class, and 'al' is an EntryList class

Comment: Oh OK. Then you can't just use toString to JSON-serialize it. Do you have a JSON library already in your project that you can use? (Are you using a framework for your server code that would already have a JSON serializer probided?)

Comment: No, I can't just use toString, because he only save a part of the json component in the file, while I would like it in full