# how can i Separate a string to many json object in java?

Tags: java, json, httpclient

i need some help : i have a string that I got with an http  GET request and in this string there is many item  written as json my question is how can i separate or retrieve this item and save it as a json file

here is how i print my response:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(responseBody);
```

Comment: Can you share a example of  the string with JSON.

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews my print is like that                                                                              { "result": [ { "name": "tom", "gender": "male", "address": {"city": "NY", "town": "US"}, "age": "20"}, { "name": "sarah", "gender": "female", "address": {"city": "NY", "town": "US"}, "age": "22"}, .... ] }

Comment: @SalahEddineBelmabrouk if you want to convert String value to json, you can check https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java Or if you want to write json to a file you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728446/write-a-json-file-in-java

Comment: @Sha but in my string i have different  json object did you understand me ?

Comment: @SalahEddineBelmabrouk, you have a jsonobject like `List<User> result`; and your User object contains `name, gender and Address(which is another class that contains city, town) fields`. So you can use gson library in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper  objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String responseBody ="{ \"result\": [ { \"name\": \"tom\", \"gender\": \"male\", \"address\": {\"city\": \"NY\", \"town\": \"US\"}, \"age\": \"20\"}, { \"name\": \"sarah\", \"gender\": \"female\", \"address\": {\"city\": \"NY\", \"town\": \"US\"}, \"age\": \"22\"}] } ";
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode jsonArray =jsonNode.get("result");
        
        if (jsonArray.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode objNode : jsonArray) {
                String fileName = String.format( "file%s.json",objNode.get("name").asText());
                objectMapper.writeValue(new File(fileName), objNode);
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Here I am converting *`responseBody`* to JsonNode object , then iterating each element of  *`result`* field and saved it as file.