# compilation error in JSONObject

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am getting compilation error in JSONObject :
`The constructor JSONObject(HashMap<String,String>) is undefined`

In this code:

```java
   import java.util.HashMap;

   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    HashMap<String, String> resJson = new HashMap<String, String>();

    resJson.put("author", author);
    resJson.put("msg", msg);

    return (new JSONObject(resJson)).toString();
```

So, can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: `JSONObject(Map)` was added in version `1.1.1`. You're apparently using an earlier version.

Comment: Thanks! With this version it's really work)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the version you are using does not have constructor which accepts map as input. try this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("author", author);
obj.put("msg", msg);
return obj.toString();
```

Comment: >       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  >       obj.putAll(resJson);
  >  return obj.toString();
I tried this and now have "Type safety: The method putAll(Map) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized". Is it normal?

Comment: You can ignore that or add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415436/json-and-generics-in-java-type-safety-warning