# Generify JSONObject string keys

Tags: java, json, eclipse, generics, compiler-warnings

I have existing code which use `org.json.JSONObject`'s Iterator

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("key1", "value1");
obj.put("key2", "value2");
Iterator keys = obj.keys();
...
```

With compile warning

> ```
> Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized
> ```

I can update to generic version:

```
Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();
```

But isn't there a way to "generify" `JSONObject` with `String` keys?

I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415436/json-and-generics-in-java-type-safety-warning) but its suggestion doesn't compiled

> ```
> JSONObject<String,Object> obj=new JSONObject<String,Object>();
> ```

**EDIT**

Using `Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();` I'm getting a type safety warning:

> ```
> Type safety: The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator<String>
> ```

Also using Eclipse Infer generics doesn't execute any code changes

Comment: Are you using `org.json.JSONObject` or `org.json.simple.JSONObject`?

Comment: @D.B. `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you provided a link to is using a different class than the one you are using. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) for `org.json.JSONObject` you'll find the following:

```
public Iterator<String> keys() {
    return this.keySet().iterator();
}
```

Which means you can write the following code:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("key1", "value1");
    obj.put("key2", "value2");
    Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(keys.next());
    }
```

and it will generate the following output:

```
key1
key2
```

Comment: But then I get a warning `Type safety: The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator<String>`

Comment: I'm using the latest version - org.json:json:20180813 and I don't get any such warning. Please provide more details about your setup.

Comment: This is a warning in Eclipse, basically you cast to String although it's not safe, you don't define JSONObject with String keys. BTW did you downvote?

Comment: @user7294900 [JSONObject has hardcoded String keys](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L909). The code given in the answer should not cause such a warning. [Generics are used since version 2014-05-03](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/commit/a9a07623834b6da2c2c3d47b440e002dedfd9e17#diff-6c8bf136596bcd17e616c3f3fb5654a4R723). Please upgrade your JSON-java dependency.