# JSON-java compilation error when put null value

Tags: java, json

I have the following (working code) with [old JSONObject jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901969/generify-jsonobject-string-keys)

```
String title = "title";
return new JSONObject()
                .put("title", title).put("url", null)));
```

When I start using the [latest jar from JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

I get a compile error

```
The method put(String, Collection<?>) is ambiguous for the type JSONObject
```

I found an [issue](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/issues/382) that suggest using `JSONObject.NULL` instead of `null`

> This library has a distinct JSONObject.NULL constant that is used to store JSON null values. It is deliberate. The Java null value is treated in this library like JavaScript undefined.
>
> While not part of the specification, I can't see us undoing this as it would break backwards compatibility.

But there's no middle way to support both JSON versions?
Should a bug be open for support backward for `JSON-java` project or am I missing something or just using unsupported old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`put("", null)` could any of the three methods in JSONObject class: `put(String key, Object value)` , `put(String key, Collection<?> value)` or `put(String key, Map<?, ?> value)`. So it could not be used anymore with the latest version of `org.json` library. To overcome this, they have defined a static class `Null` of their own : `org.json.JSONObject.Null` which when used in `put` will call `put(String key, Object value)` method.